# Request parameters lost when calling via artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan

when in artisan command create request with parameter to call a route, destination route dose not receive request parameters.

testcommand:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'route:run';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $date = [
        'username' => 'test',

    ];
    $tokenRequest = Request::create('/test', 'post', $date);
    $res = app()->handle($tokenRequest)->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
    $responseBody = json_decode($res->getContent());
    var_dump($responseBody);
}
}
```

and my controller is:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request;

 class ExampleController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function test(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'username'=>'required'
    ]);
    return $request->all();
}

 }
```

and route is:

```
$router->post('/test','ExampleController@test');
```

another things is default of lumen.
when we run php artisan route:run in terminal, destination route does not get included parameter.

Comment: first question, why are you dispatching a request in your command?

Comment: `php artisan` and Lumen? Are you mixing Laravel and Lumen?

Comment: @lagbox we need call route with parameter in pub/sub, command subscribe channel and when receive data need to call route and pass parameter to that.

Comment: why do you need to call a route? can't you refactor that code out of the controller and call it directly? just wondering

Comment: that is shared between user and command. Otherwise we have to repeat a structure twice

Comment: You could just refactor your duplicated code into another command or an action class and call it directly from your controller and command.

Comment: this solution is for auto testing route every hour. and we should refactor all project code?! we need a answer not solution to refactor